# How do unique_ptrs prevent the cyclic dependency problem in C++?

Tags: c++

We know that shared_ptr can have a cyclic dependecy. For example, if object A has a shared_ptr member that points to object B, and object B has a shared_ptr memeber that points to object A, then both objects will "live" until end of program, since the use_count will never be 0.

Why is it not the case if we switched, in the example above, shared_ptr to unique_ptr?
A would still point to B and vice versa, so we can not delete neither of them.

Edit: as requested in the comments, a small (contrived) example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

using namespace std;

class B;

class A{
    public:
    unique_ptr<B> a_ptr;
};

class B{
    public:
    unique_ptr<A> b_ptr;
};

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    A* a = new A();
    B* b = new B();
    a->a_ptr.reset(b);
    b->b_ptr.reset(a);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: They don't prevent it. It's only slightly harder to end up with one because `unique_ptr` can't be copied, and you'd have to `move` it.

Comment: To create such a cycle with unique pointers, you'd have to deliberately hand a raw pointer you did not create yourself to the unique_ptr constructor. That is an immediate code smell.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat - I tried to conjure an example with just moves of unique pointers, and found myself rather stuck. I'd be interested to see an example, if you have the time.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica same - I can't see how without involving raw pointers at some point in the chain of logic (even if only temporarily).

Comment: @MikeVine - I kept trying. Came up at this https://wandbox.org/permlink/w6WTpAeX0XBsfpgH - but it seems too contrived to me still

Comment: if it wouldnt be possible to use it wrong it wouldnt be c++ ;). Seriously, C++ never tried to be foolproof. `std::unique_ptr` makes it much harder to get it wrong. If you try hard you can still do something wrong. Trying to prevent all kinds of possible mistakes would inadvertently also prevent totally valid uses and/or make the langauge much more complicated. Other languages try to be foolproof, they are not, but still they prevent you from doing things that are not possible merely because they try to be foolproof. Thats not c++

Comment: This is just my unsubstantiated opinion, but I feel that if you use `unique_ptr` conscientiously and with ownership in mind, it will be very hard (but not impossible) to reach a point where such a cycle happens "organically".

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica *"Came up at this"* This is what I had in mind.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica Or, more simply: https://godbolt.org/z/MnMK3s45P

Comment: is `p->p = std::move(p);` well defined? You are _moving_ from `p` (on RHS) and also reading from `p` (on LHS). What's the sequence here which supports this? @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica

Comment: @MikeVine - `std::move` is a cast that doesn't modify the underlying pointer, and since C++17 is sequenced before `p->p`, and both before the assignment itself even before C++17. Nevertheless this isn't really too relevant since the assignment is actually inside a function call to an overloaded `operator=` in this case, when all computations and side effects of the arguments are done.

Comment: when you have some `A` that owns `B` and at the same time `B` owns directly or indirectly `A`, then thats a flaw in your design, and no smart pointer can cure a broken design. Its the unintentional loops that `std::unique_ptr` avoids, simply by not being copyable. Once you call `std::move` or call `reset` you do that intentionally and its explicit in your code. Its nothing that slips in implicitly as it would eg with raw pointers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A `unique_ptr` does not prevent ownership cycles. There are fewer ways in which such a cycle can come up, but more than none. Whatever resource told you otherwise is mistaken.

What is correct is that it is easier to create an ownership cycle with shared pointers. An object could easily keep a copy of a shared pointer in order to keep a needed resource – created and owned by someone else – alive. Your object doesn't know much about the resource other than it exists. Your object is not aware that the resource needs another resource, so the resource did the same thing, copy a shared pointer. In a dynamic program, needs change, so it might be that at some point one of these indirectly needed resources is given a shared pointer to your object, resulting in a cycle. In a sense, too many chefs (owners) spoiled the soup.

With a `unique_ptr`, there is no latching onto someone else's object. Ownership usually has a clear direction, from certain objects to others, leaving no room for a cycle. Usually. But not always. As you noted, it is possible to create an ownership cycle with `unique_ptr`.

### Example

In the interest of having a less contrived example, let's talk about <s>no one's</s> everyone's favorite subject, <s>taxes</s> money. :) There is a tax concept called "dependent" which basically means that one person can <s>mooch off of</s> be supported by another. In the below code, we model the scenario where one person gets fired and has to rely on someone else, a.k.a. move back in with the parents. *(For those who missed the humor: this is intended as a fun exercise, and any resemblance to reality is <s>purely coincidental</s> in your head.)*

This code is simplified to focus on the ownership cycle that will be created. There are plenty of ways to add things to make it more "realistic", but my intent is not realism. My goal is to present a plausible setup, then create an ownership cycle with a simple typo.

(The code blocks should be combined into one file, but I'm adding some commentary along the way.)

#### The "human" element

Start with a type to represent a person. This is the object that will be leaked, so it logs construction and destruction. I even remembered to log the copy constructor, even though that will not come into play.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

struct TaxPayer {
    // For simplicity, support at most one dependent instead using of a vector.
    std::unique_ptr<TaxPayer> dependent;

    // Log construction and destruction,
    TaxPayer() { std::cout << "TaxPayer()\n"; }
    TaxPayer(const TaxPayer&) { std::cout << "TaxPayer(copy)\n"; }
    ~TaxPayer() { std::cout << "~TaxPayer()\n"; }
};
```

#### Home, sweet home

Next, we model a "household", which for our purposes is more of a place to send bills than anything related to "family". Often a dependent moves out and establishes a new "household", but we need to support the reverse direction as well. So this type provides a method for abandoning the household and becoming a dependent.

```cpp
struct Household {
    // For simplicity, support at most one income per household.
    std::unique_ptr<TaxPayer> bread_winner;

    // For convenience, default to having someone in the household.
    Household() : bread_winner(std::make_unique<TaxPayer>()) {}

    // Stuff happens. The bread winner becomes unemployed and
    // abandons the house to live off someone else.
    void becomeDependentOn(TaxPayer& sponsor) {
        sponsor.dependent = std::move(bread_winner);
    }
};
```

#### Use better variable names!

So far I have avoided undesirable elements like raw pointers (code smell) and contrived indirection. Now, though, I will give in and use variable names that are not particularly descriptive. This allows a simple typo to break things.

```cpp
int main()
{
    Household house1;
    Household house2;

    // Assume some processing was done, and now it's time
    // to move house2 into house1 as a dependent.
    house1.becomeDependentOn(*house1.bread_winner);
    // Oops! That line was supposed to be:
    //house2.becomeDependentOn(*house1.bread_winner);
}
```

Oh no! I used the wrong variable. When I run this code, I get

```
TaxPayer()
TaxPayer()
~TaxPayer()
```

Two objects were created, but only one was destroyed. The object that survived managed to become its own dependent!

The kicker is that changing one character removes the memory leak. It's not stellar coding, but I think it falls under "plausible" rather than "contrived".

Answer (score 1):

That's right, they both still point to each other, except they don't know about it (they don't count the references like shared pointers do).

What will generally happen is, as soon as one of those unique pointers is destroyed, it will delete the pointer. Then, when the *other* unique pointer is destroyed (goes out of scope or for whatever other reason, that's it's job after all), it will attempt to delete the same pointer *again*, which invokes undefined behaviour (a crash if things go "well").

Comment: With the caveat, that neither of the two pointers can be destroyed, because they are supposed to be "unique" pointers to the objects. In other words; There is no "path" by which either one can be destroyed Unless we lied, and there was sneakily a second unique_ptr to one of them ;-)

Comment: I'd say their uniqueness makes it so they can't, ordinarily, both be _created_ to point to the same object. But if you've managed that (probably by manually handling raw pointers, as per @StoryTeller's comment), then desctruction follows, literally and figuratively. Note that it's not that the pointers are pointing to each other (what would their types be?) but to their respective owning objects.

Answer (score 0):

As @HolyBlackCat and @StoryTeller pointed out in the comments, such loops can easily be created by moving a `unique_ptr`s around. For example take the following example:

```
1  #include <iostream>
2  #include <memory>
3  #include <utility>
4
5  struct X {
6      X() {
7          std::cout << "created\n";
8      }
9  
10     ~X() {
11         std::cout << "destroyed\n";
12     }
13
14     std::unique_ptr<X> ptr{};
15 };
16
17 int main() {
18     auto x1 = std::make_unique<X>();
19     auto x2 = std::make_unique<X>();
20
21     auto& x1_ref = *x1;
22
23     x1->ptr = std::move(x2);
24     x1->ptr->ptr = std::move(x1);
25
26     x1_ref.ptr.reset();  // destroy the loop by resetting one of the ptrs
27 }
```

[live on compiler explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/6G6Yd5xx4)

Note that the statement in line 24 invalidates the `x1` pointer. If we had not created a reference to the actual object in line 21, we would be unable to access, change or even delete the objects in the loop. Only throuh this reference (could also be an ordinary pointer) it is possible to destroy the loop again. However, taking a reference or raw pointer to an object that is managed by a `unique_ptr` is usually considered bad practice, because it bypasses the ownership management (consider what happens if line 26 is happening somewhere else and the programmer uses `x1_ref` after resetting one of its members not thinking about the possibility that the reference itself could be spuriously invalidated).

---

Now to answer your question. `unique_ptr`s do **not** prevent the cyclic dependency problem, but it is a little bit harder to create a cycle. Smart pointers are a solution for many accidental programmer errors, but do not migitate intended misuse. You still have to think properly about ownership.

Comment: `x1->ptr->ptr = std::move(x1);`. You are moving from `x1` on the RHS (which clears it) and reading from in on the LHS. Is this well defined behaviour? It feels like it's not although I'm not language lawyer.

Comment: @MikeVine: `std::move` doesn't "clear" `x1`, it is just a cast to treat it as r-value, the assignation clears it (but we already have evaluated `x1->` at that stage).